# Group-by and coalesce cannot be combined, gives an error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, group-by, coalesce

I am creating an SSRS report and while making the data queries to it I got into this error. I do need the data set (Month to Date and Year to Date values) in one row connected with a group by command. [This is the crystal report I'm referring to and converting to SSRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymp0J.png).

The error I get is something like : `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Note: I cannot use 2 sub queries such as one for MTD and one for YTD values since values does not match with the row description. That is the whole reason I'm trying to use some `coalesce` functions with individual group-by commands.

What I have tried :

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
SELECT coalesce((Select ((SUM( "IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."sls_amt")-SUM( "IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."cost_amt"))/SUM( "IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."sls_amt"))*100 ),0) AS G1MTD,
       "IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."Mainslspsn_name",
       "IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."PCSummarized",
       coalesce ((SELECT SUM("IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."qty_to_ship"-"IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."qty_return_to_stk")FROM "100"."dbo"."IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"
   where Year = 2021
   and Month between 1 and 12
   Group by Mainslspsn_name,PCSummarized),0) AS Qty_Sold,
       coalesce ((SELECT SUM("IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."sls_amt")FROM "100"."dbo"."IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"
   where Year = 2021
   and Month between 1 and 12
   Group by Mainslspsn_name,PCSummarized),0) AS YTD_Sales,
       coalesce ((SELECT SUM("IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."cost_amt")FROM "100"."dbo"."IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"
   where Year = 2021
   and Month between 1 and 12
   Group by Mainslspsn_name,PCSummarized),0) AS YTD_COGS,
       coalesce((Select ((SUM( "IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."sls_amt")-SUM( "IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."cost_amt"))/SUM( "IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."sls_amt"))*100 
       FROM "100"."dbo"."IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"
   where Year = 2021
   and Month between 1 and 12
   Group by Mainslspsn_name,PCSummarized),0) AS G2YTD,
        SUM("IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."qty_to_ship"-"IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."qty_return_to_stk") 
        AS Qty_Sold,
        SUM("IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."sls_amt") 
        AS MTD_Sales,
        SUM("IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"."cost_amt") 
        AS MTD_COGS   
   FROM "100"."dbo"."IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"
   where Year = 2021
   and Month = 12
   Group by Mainslspsn_name,PCSummarized
   order by PCSummarized
```

The issue is with the individual group-by commands following with the coalesce I feel like, because without those the query works but only returns the same total sum value for all the rows.  [Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUWie.png)

Here is a sample dataset for reference :

```
CREATE TABLE IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp
    ([Mainslspsn_no](int)
      ,[Mainslspsn_name](char(64))
      ,[PCSummarized](char(75))
      ,[Year](int)
      ,[Month](int)
      ,[MonthLit](varchar(3))
      ,[PCSummary](varchar(24))
      ,[slspsn_no](int)
      ,[fullname](char(64))
      ,[cus_no](char(20))
      ,[cus_name](char(50))
      ,[inv_dt](datetime)
      ,[sls_amt](decimal(16,2))
      ,[cost_amt](decimal(16,2))
      ,[item_no](char(30))
      ,[item_desc_1](char(30))
      ,[item_desc_2](char(30))
      ,[prod_cat](char(3))
      ,[prod_cat_desc](char(15))
      ,[qty_ordered](decimal(13,4))
      ,[qty_to_ship](decimal(13,4))
      ,[qty_return_to_stk](decimal(13,4))
      ,[unit_price](decimal(16,6))
      ,[unit_cost](decimal(16,6))
      ,[state](char(3))
      ,[city](varchar(100))
      ,[zip](varchar(20))
      ,[cus_type_cd](char(5))
      ,[loc](char(3)))
;

INSERT INTO IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp
    ([Mainslspsn_no]
      ,[Mainslspsn_name]
      ,[PCSummarized]
      ,[Year]
      ,[Month]
      ,[MonthLit]
      ,[PCSummary]
      ,[slspsn_no]
      ,[fullname]
      ,[cus_no]
      ,[cus_name]
      ,[inv_dt]
      ,[sls_amt]
      ,[cost_amt]
      ,[item_no]
      ,[item_desc_1]
      ,[item_desc_2]
      ,[prod_cat]
      ,[prod_cat_desc]
      ,[qty_ordered]
      ,[qty_to_ship]
      ,[qty_return_to_stk]
      ,[unit_price]
      ,[unit_cost]
      ,[state]
      ,[city]
      ,[zip]
      ,[cus_type_cd]
      ,[loc])
VALUES
    (849, 'Paul Dean','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 849, 'Paul Dean', '123456','ABC PRODUCTS','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',357.60,288.35,'01583220126','126 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',80.0000,80.0000,0.0000,4.470000,3.604391,'NC','SHELBY','28152','ASII8','FL'),
    (849, 'Paul Dean','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 849, 'Paul Dean', '123456','ABC PRODUCTS','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',357.60,310.57,'01583220142','142 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',80.0000,80.0000,0.0000,4.470000,3.882166,'NC','SHELBY','28152','ASII8','FL'),
    (849, 'Paul Dean','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 849, 'Paul Dean', '122334','XYZ PRODUCTS','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',56.76,33.47,'01583220098','98 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (849, 'Paul Dean','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 849, 'Paul Dean', '122334','XYZ PRODUCTS','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',56.76,74.83,'01583220098','98 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (849, 'Paul Dean','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 849, 'Paul Dean', '122334','XYZ PRODUCTS','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',189.20,127.29,'01583220098','98 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (201, 'John Snider','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 201, 'John Snider', '107974','CDE SUPPLIES','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',205.92,120.87,'01583220098','98 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (201, 'John Snider','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 201, 'John Snider', '107974','CDE SUPPLIES','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',977.60,570.48,'01583220098','98 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (201, 'John Snider','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 201, 'John Snider', '107974','CDE SUPPLIES','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',146.64,86.41,'01583220098','98 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (201, 'John Snider','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 201, 'John Snider', '107974','CDE SUPPLIES','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',293.28,180.30,'01583220098','98 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (201, 'John Snider','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 201, 'John Snider', '107974','CDE SUPPLIES','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',293.28,186.11,'01583220098','98 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (207, 'House Accounts','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 207, 'House Accounts', '107974','SUPERIOR PRODUCTS','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',365.60,215.32,'01583220065','65 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (207, 'House Accounts','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 207, 'House Accounts', '107974','SUPERIOR PRODUCTS','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',365.60,233.08,'0158422008014','80-1/4 X 5/8 X 022 4T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (207, 'House Accounts','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 207, 'House Accounts', '107974','SUPERIOR PRODUCTS','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',1506.00,1099.40,'01583220124','124 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (207, 'House Accounts','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 207, 'House Accounts', '107974','SUPERIOR PRODUCTS','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',502.00,375.76,'01583220126','126 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL'),
    (207, 'House Accounts','Band Saw Blades', 2022,3, 'Mar', 'Bandsaw Blades', 207, 'House Accounts', '107974','SUPERIOR PRODUCTS','2022-03-16 00:00:00.000',9036.00,6988.46,'0158322012913','129-1/3 X 5/8 X 022 3T PREMIUM',,106,'BLD-5/8 X 022',24.0000,24.0000,0.0000,4.780000,3.117917,'FL','BOYNTON BEACH','33472','CII18','FL')
;
```

Comment: What about the error don't you understand. The error is telling you the problem. Several of the subqueries you have are certainly going to return multiple rows as they aren't correlated and have a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Do you not actually want conditional aggregation here? You aren't under the impression that your references to `"100"."dbo"."IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"` in your subqueries are the same "instance" as the one in the outer `FROM` are you? That isn't how SQL works; each reference to `"100"."dbo"."IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp"` would be a separate "instance" of the table.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand the error. That's the reason I'm asking whether is it not possible to have group-by and coalesce combined together since that's the only way I found to get my query straightened.

Comment: `COALESCE` and `GROUP BY` have no relation, EDMT. The reason for your error is, as I stated, some of your subqueries are returning multiple rows; specifically the ones which have a `GROUP BY` clause, as you are getting one row per distinct group. Without sample data, and expected results, however, then we can do little more than guess what you *actually* want; and i don't often add guess answers.

Comment: Larnu, thank you very much for that clarification. But why would the queries throw an error when returning multiple values even when I'm not asking for distinct values? Pardon my lack of SQL knowledge here, I'm trying to learn as I get into errors. Also a sample dataset is given above in the question if that helps? My expected result is also the same as the one in the picture(crystal report I'm referring to and converting to SSRS). Thank you again.

Comment: `SET ARITHABORT OFF SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` what do you think this does and why do you think you need it?

Comment: Take one of your subqueries with a `GROUP BY` and run it on it's own; you'll see the rows it returns.

Comment: Side note, your DDL isn't valid; data types don't go in parenthesis (`()`).

Comment: Charlieface : I'm using that to avoid getting the infinity after the divide by zeros. That was the easiest way I could find to avoid that error.

Comment: Why not use `NULLIF({divisor expression},0)`?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use UNION with a "zeroed" row and add an aggregate :

```
WITH 
T1 AS
(
SELECT (
       SELECT((SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.sls_amt) - SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.cost_amt)) / SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.sls_amt)) * 100) AS G1MTD, 
       IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.Mainslspsn_name, 
       IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.PCSummarized, 
       (
       SELECT SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.qty_to_ship - IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.qty_return_to_stk)
       FROM "100".dbo.IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp
       WHERE Year = 2021
             AND Month BETWEEN 1 AND 12
       GROUP BY Mainslspsn_name, 
                PCSummarized) AS Qty_Sold, 
       (
       SELECT SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.sls_amt)
       FROM "100".dbo.IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp
       WHERE Year = 2021
             AND Month BETWEEN 1 AND 12
       GROUP BY Mainslspsn_name, 
                PCSummarized) AS YTD_Sales, 
      (
       SELECT SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.cost_amt)
       FROM "100".dbo.IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp
       WHERE Year = 2021
             AND Month BETWEEN 1 AND 12
       GROUP BY Mainslspsn_name, 
                PCSummarized) AS YTD_COGS, 
       (
       SELECT((SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.sls_amt) - SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.cost_amt)) / SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.sls_amt)) * 100
       FROM "100".dbo.IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp
       WHERE Year = 2021
             AND Month BETWEEN 1 AND 12
       GROUP BY Mainslspsn_name, 
                PCSummarized) AS G2YTD, 
       SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.qty_to_ship - IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.qty_return_to_stk) AS Qty_Sold2, --> renamed because ambigous
       SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.sls_amt) AS MTD_Sales, 
       SUM(IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp.cost_amt) AS MTD_COGS
FROM "100".dbo.IS_vwSalesbyProductLineComp
WHERE Year = 2021
      AND Month = 12
GROUP BY Mainslspsn_name, 
         PCSummarized
),
T2 AS 
(
SELECT 0 AS C1, '' AS C2, '' AS C3, 0 AS C4, 0 AS C5, 0 AS C6, 0 AS C7, 0 AS C8, 0 AS C9, 0 AS C10
),
T3 AS
(
SELECT * FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T2
)
SELECT SUM(G1MTD) AS G1MTD, 
       STRING_AGG(Mainslspsn_name, '') AS Mainslspsn_name,
       STRING_AGG(PCSummarized, '') AS PCSummarized,
       SUM(Qty_Sold) AS Qty_Sold,
       SUM(YTD_Sales) AS YTD_Sales,
       SUM(YTD_COGS) AS YTD_COGS,
       SUM(G2YTD) AS G2YTD,
       SUM(Qty_Sold2) AS Qty_Sold2,
       SUM(MTD_Sales) AS MTD_Sales,
       SUM(MTD_COGS) AS MTD_COGS
FROM T3
ORDER BY PCSummarized;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I'm getting error : 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name. Probably since I'm using SSMS 15.0.18369.0. Any replacement I could use for that function?

Comment: STRING_AGG is perfectly known in version 15 (SQL 2019). What returns the query : "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion'), compatibility_level
FROM  sys.databases WHERE  name = DB_NAME()" ?

Comment: I do see 12 and 120 as the compatibility_level.

Comment: Which means that you are using a SQL Server 2014 that does'nt have STRING_AGG. You must replace the STRING_AGG by an XML aggregation construction. Reads https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/a-couple-quick-notes-on-using-xml-for-string-aggregation/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So I have removed the STRING_AGG function and tried still getting this "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." error. Anything to resolve this errir? Thank you!